# In R, calculate % of rows that are true

Tags: r

How to calculate % of rows that are true in a data set? See example data frame and output below
dataframe

```
ID Present
1  True
2  True
3  True
4  False 
5  False
```

example output 1

```
60%
```

example output 2

```
.60
```

Comment: `mean(df$Present)`

Answer (score 1):

Using base R you could do:

```
mean(as.logical(df$Present))
[1] 0.6
```

You can multiply that by 100

```
prop.table(table(df$Present))
```

or even:

```
mosaic::tally(~Present, df, format = 'proportion')
Present
False  True 
  0.4   0.6 

mosaic::tally(~Present, df, format = 'percent')
Present
False  True 
   40    60
```

Comment: With a note that `mean(df$Present)` only works if they are actual logical `TRUE` and `FALSE` values, not a character vector with `True` and `False`. (+1)